# Getting "RPC error, code: 7, details: Read Aloud Service has not been used" with Google Read Aloud Embedded Player

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I am facing an issue with the Google Read Aloud Embedded Player implementation on my website. Whenever I try to use the player, I receive the following error message: "RPC error, code: 7, details: Read Aloud Service has not been used in project 543...".

Here is the implementation code I am using:

```
<google-read-aloud-player
  id="tts-player"
  data-url="<BLOG POST URL>"
  data-api-key="<API_KEY>"
  data-tracking-ids="G-XXXXXXX"
  data-voice="en-AU"
></google-read-aloud-player>

<script
  async=""
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/readaloud/player/web/api/js/api.js"
></script>
```

I have already enabled the "text to speech" service in the Google Cloud Console and created an API key. However, despite these steps, I am still encountering this error.

I would appreciate any guidance or insights on how to resolve this issue and successfully use the Google Read Aloud Embedded Player. Thank you in advance for your help!